# Sympa commands silently fail

Tags: debian, postfix, sympa

I have a Postfix server on a Debian box and I use Sympa for mailing-lists. The mailing-lists work fine (the messages are correctly distributed to suscribers) but sympa commands don't work.

When I send an email to sympa@example.org, it appears in mail.log:

```
Sep  7 16:23:14 quai10 postfix/local[31032]: D01991434: to=<sympa@example.org>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

But no answer is sent and nothing appears in `sympa.log`.

Do you have any idea where this could come from?

*PS: I can provide config files if needed.*

Comment: *Always* provide config files. We are not fortunetellers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, I was missing this line in /etc/aliases:

```
sympa:          "|/usr/lib/sympa/bin/queue sympa"
```